# how to remove the -j9 option from the build process in gnome-builder

Tags: gnome, vala

I have an existing Vala project (using automake) that builds perfectly fine from the command prompt, but it fails when the build process is initiated from gnome-builder. The problem is a parallelism issue. gnome-builder is inserting a -j9 during make.

```
make 'all' '-j9'
```

How do I remove the -j9 option? or at least set it to -j1.
I've tried setting from Preferences, Build->Build Workers to 1, but this doesn't seem to change anything. The version of gnome-builder is 3.22.2.

Comment: If there are missing dependencies causing a race in make, then you should track it down and fix it... Other people's make configuration will be different from yours, so they'll run into the same problem even if you work around it.

Comment: I read somewhere that automake currently does not support parallel builds for vala. If someone can point me to an Makefile.am example that includes vapi generation,that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776708.
It is now fixed. Preferences, Build->Build Workers now functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

How is the setup below in your project? Change it to 1.

[image]

Comment: I've set it to various values including 1 (As mentioned in the original question). It doesn't  change anything. I'm wondering if it is a bug?